# Finding All Values in Pandas DataFrame Not of Certain Type

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

To avoid the following error, I would like to replace any integer in my DataFrame with [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array

In a small subset of the Excel files I'm reading in, I know the integers that appear are 0. However, what if there were multiple distinct integers? Or what if there are multiple dtypes? How can I easily replace any non-datetimes with the epoch represented datetime?

This works for the simple case of replacing 0s:

```
for col_name in time_columns:
    time_col = data[col_name]
    if time_col.dtypes is np.dtype('object'):
        time_col.replace(to_replace=0, value=epoch, inplace=True)
    time_col = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_col).astype(np.int64)/10**6
    data[col_name] = time_col
```

where

```
epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) or [issubclass()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass)